# Align shapes to grid 'off centre'

Tags: microsoft-visio

I have some oddly shaped shapes that I want to stick to a regular grid pattern.

[image]

Unfortunately, because the shape's alignment box is 'off centre' relative to the grid, using 'Snap to Alignment Box' doesn't produce the desired alignment.

[image]

What is the best way to make these shapes snap to the desired grid?

One (ugly) way is to draw a box around the entire shape, then use Shapesheet properties to set this box to "not visible". The alignment box is forced to the size of the hidden box, and you can make this box be a nice multiple of the grid spacing. This works, but it's a bit of a hack.

Is there a simpler and easier way of achieving the same result?

Comment: Answered externally - http://visguy.com/vgforum/index.php?topic=5749.0 .

Answer (score 0):

The shapes may be designed for either a metric or inch division grid. Ensure you are using suitable measurement settings for your page.

Answer (score 0):

In master shape, put a box around it, then group so it matches the grid. You can accurately position your stuff in the box. Then, as a group, carefully select the box and delete it, leaving the group outline.